# inotify_log file deletion and disk space usage

Tags: linux

I could see the inotify_log-20160224 file present in my cPanel server using nearly 43G so I gone ahead and removed it ( rm -rf inotify_log-20160224 ) but my disk space use still showing the same usage ( It doesn't  decreased ), Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed  my inotify log with rm -rf command and the deletion process stuck. So to remove this log file completely I have used

```
lsof |grep 'deleted' command
```

This command show currently running deletion process. Get the process ID of this process and terminate it with kill -9